# Error en post: Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_AB_A_B_BId"

Tags: sql-server, angular, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

Ya en mi aplicación, al momento de hacer un post me sale el siguiente error en la consola:

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while saving the entity changes. See the inner exception for details.
> ---> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_productosCategorias_categorias_categoriasId". The conflict occurred in database "productos", table "dbo.categorias", column 'Id'.
> The statement has been terminated.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No entiendo porque hay un conflicto con la tabla categorias, cuando el post es el controller de productos, en la tabla productos.

```
       [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Post([FromForm] ProductosCreacionDTO productosCreacionDTO)
    {
        var productos = mapper.Map<productos>(productosCreacionDTO);

        if (productosCreacionDTO.rutaImagen != null)
        {
            productos.rutaImagen = await almacenadorArchivos.GuardarArchivo(contenedor, productosCreacionDTO.rutaImagen);
        }
        _context.Add(productos);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync(true);
        return NoContent();
    }
```

Y si es necesario puedo incluir las entidades/DTO's y las bases de datos, les agradezco la ayuda. :D

Comment: Es un 500, es de parte del servidor... hay mil opciones.

Comment: El mensaje de error es clarísimo: el INSERT, de realizarse, violaría una restricción de integridad referencial (por ejemplo, crearía registros huérfanos). Supongamos que hay dos tablas relacionadas, pero intentas insertar un valor de llave foránea (FK) que no existe en la tabla padre ... tendrás este tipo de error, porque ese valor no existe en la tabla padre, creando un registro huérfano. El SGBD te dice: *para insertar este registro con esta FK primero debe existir en la tabla padre*.

Comment: Estás tratando de ingresar en productos un producto con un id que no existe en categorías (como extra, deberías manejar tus entidades en la bd en singular)

Comment: @ndrs Tu respuesta me llevó a solucionar mi problema, ya que tenía una incosistencia entre mi modelo categoria y el ApplicationDbContext, para ser especifico, uno lo tenía cómo "categoriasID" y otro cómo "categoriaID", habiendo 3 columnas en la tabla productoCategorias, y eso me daba el error, muchísimas gracias!